# CakePHP production deployment requiring me to set debug '2'

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, deployment

I am having an issue in my automated deployment where once the deployment is made, I get a 500 error unless I go into `/app/Config/core.php` and set the debug level to `2`. I have read that this has to do with the cache.

When I deploy my site, I keep the `app/tmp/cache` folder and its permissions, but not its contents, and I figured this would be enough, but it is not. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Probably want to keep the tmp/models and tmp/persistent folders too (just not their contents)

Comment: OK, I'll try that too.

Comment: Thanks @Dave! That seems to have worked. If you'd like to make that an answer, I'd be happy to give you the credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to keep your `tmp/models` and `tmp/persistent` folders.  You can delete their contents, but leave the actual folders.